# Multi-Dimensional array accessing in livewire and laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-livewire, livewires

I am trying to get the values from my checkboxes which are multi dimensional. what i tried is as shown in code but i am getting empty array . Kindly help please

```js
<input type="checkbox" checked class="parent"
wire:model="permission.view.{{ $menu['id'] }}"
data-size="medium"
name="permission[view][{{$menu['id']}}]" value="{{ $menu['id'] }}">


public $view = [];
    public $permission = [
        [
            "view" => ""
        ]
    ];
```

How can i achieve this. Kindly Help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return permission if that is your question.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked class="parent"
wire:model="permission.view.{{ $menu['id'] }}"
data-size="medium"
name="permission[view][{{$menu['id']}}]" value="{{ $menu['id'] }}">
```

This will be filled up with the checked items

```
public $permission = [];
```

you can use this @json($permission) on your blade component to see the return you will get when a checkbox is checked.